# Choose SIM card when sending SMS on a dual SIM Android device

Tags: android, numbers, emulation

I have created a basic application to send SMS to users, but it does not run well on my Android device with dual SIM cards.

Is there any way code to let the application choose between the first and second SIM card?

Comment: the sim card to send message is selected for the user in dual sim settings ( android general settings )  in preferred sim settings